# Estimating the ratio between the square of the sample mean and the second moment of the sample mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator

Suppose $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are i.i.d. and have the $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution. I'm interested in finding an unbiased estimator for
$$
  \rho := \frac{\mu^2}{\mu^2 + \sigma^2/n}.
$$

##### A naive approach

Consider the ratio between the unbiased estimators for $\mu^2$ and $\mu^2 + \sigma^2/n$.
Denoting $\hat \sigma^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2$ to be the unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$, and observing that $E (\bar y^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2/n$ we reach the following quantity:
$$
  \hat \rho := \frac{\bar y^2 - \frac{1}{n}\hat \sigma^2}{\bar y^2} = 1- \frac{\hat \sigma^2}{n \bar y^2}.
$$

Now, $\hat \sigma^2\sim\chi^2_n$ and $\bar y^2$ has the noncentral chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom. If we make the standard assumption that these estimators are independent, their ratio will have (up to a constant) the [doubly noncentral F-ratio distribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NoncentralFRatioDistribution.html), which has no expected value for these parameters. As a result, $\hat \rho$ cannot be used as a basis for an unbiased estimator.

Are there other approaches I could try?